# How to prevent a duplicate item from being generated in a Foreach loop in C#

Tags: c#, foreach

I have a foreach loop which builds search results and sometimes it would return the same Page Name and Description, but the link would be different as it has a 3rd party Gallery Module which has different queries in the URL.

For example:

`Resources/Videos/emodule/936/eitem/75` would have one video

and

`/Resources/Videos/emodule/936/eitem/73` would be different.

The Title and Description is the same.

How would I change my foreach loop to check if the Page Title is the same and if it is the same, exclude the `sb.AppendLine` search result?

This is my current code:

```
TotalPageResults = "0";
var searchResults = SearchController.Instance.ModuleSearch(query);

if(searchResults != null)
{
    TotalPageResults = searchResults.TotalHits.ToString();
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("<div class='page_results'><span class='page_results_text'>Page Results:</span></br>");
    foreach(var result in searchResults.Results)
    {
        sb.AppendLine($"</br><span><a href='{result.Url}' class='page_results_link'>{result.Title}</a></span></br><span class='page_result_description'>{result.Description}</span></br><span class='page_results_date_modified'>Updated: {result.DisplayModifiedTime}</span></br>");
    }
    sb.AppendLine("</div>");
    DNNSearchResuls = sb.ToString(); 
}
```

Comment: Easiest way is to create a string collection that you add the titles to of each result object as you loop, and at the beginning of the loop you check if it contains the current result object's title.

Comment: What is the problem with this code?

Comment: select distinct results using title field or group them by title and select first from the result

Comment: I think he still wants the individual items that have the same title but without displaying the title again? Not sure.

Comment: @Thierry, there is no problem with this code. I need a suggestion on how to create an IF statement which will prevent the same item from being returned in the result view.

Comment: The URL would be different, but it is actually the same page. The Title is the same and I would to check this to prevent duplicate results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would could check if the Stringbuilder already contains the title and description. Somthing along the lines:

```
foreach(var result in searchResults.Results)
    {
        if(!sb.ToString().Contains(result.Title) && !sb.ToString().Contains(result.Description)
            sb.AppendLine($"</br><span><a href='{result.Url}' class='page_results_link'>{result.Title}</a></span></br><span class='page_result_description'>{result.Description}</span></br><span class='page_results_date_modified'>Updated: {result.DisplayModifiedTime}</span></br>");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This'll be a lot less efficient that Daves answer because the contains will have to search through all that html each time for a match instead of exact matches with .Contains() on the HashSet<String>.

Comment: ohyeh, efficiency down the toilet, but it'll work I guess :)

Answer (score 2):

Keep a set of results you've already seen, and check if it's new before 'doing the thing'

```
        var stuffImThinkinAbout = new List<string>();
        var stuffIAlreadyHave = new HashSet<string>();

        foreach (var i in stuffImThinkinAbout)
        {
            if (!stuffIAlreadyHave.Contains(i))
            {
                //do the thing
                stuffIAlreadyHave.Add(i);
            }
            else
            { 
                //skip dupe
            }
        }
```

Then use title or whatever as your 'key' to make them unique.

Comment: You don't, you extract the title (or title + description) from the result you're thinkin about, then check if that combo (think of it as a key) is in your alreadySeenList. If it isn't in the list, do your usual logic, then add it to the list. If it IS in the list, you've already handled this result earlier, so do-nothing. Once you've looped through all the results, alreadySeenList is now useless, since the 'real data' is in your stringbuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `GroupBy` on the property you want to distinct and select only one record in the group.

This code for only property `Title`

```
   foreach (var result in searchResults.Results.GroupBy(p => p.Title).Select(g => g.First())
   {
   }
```

or 2 properties `Title` and `Description`

```
foreach (var result in searchResults.Results.GroupBy(p => new {p.Title, p.Description}).Select(g => g.First())
{
}
```